Nested Permuations with filenames
I am looking to create a program that can process nested template strings along with filenames. So for example:
Template string:
The {person, fox, bear, joe, mary, lou, {animals.txt}} jumped over the car
Contents of animals.txt
cat
dog
fox
Generated strings:
[generated strings before animals.txt]...
The cat jumped over the car
The dog jumped over the car
The fox jumped over the car
I have already created a function called expand_template() to expand text files and to populate the template string, here it is:
def expand_template(template_string):
        # Find all template variables in the string
        template_vars = re.findall(r'{(\w+\.txt)}', template_string)
        # Dictionary to store the contents of each template file
        var_contents = {}

        # Read the contents of each template file
        for var in template_vars:
            if os.path.isfile(var):
                with open(var, 'r') as file:
                    var_contents[var] = [line.strip() for line in file]
            else:
                print(f"File not found: {var}")
                sys.exit(1)

        # Replace template variables with their contents
        for var in template_vars:
            template_string = template_string.replace('{' + var + '}', '{' + ','.join(var_contents[var]) + '}')

        return template_string


and here is the function to generate permutations:
def generate_permutations(template_string):
    # Find all template variables in the string
    variables = re.findall(r'{([^}]+)}', template_string)

    # Extract the options for each variable
    options = [var.split(', ') for var in variables]

    # Generate all possible combinations of options
    combinations = list(itertools.product(*options))

    permutations = []
    for combination in combinations:
        # Replace each variable with its corresponding option
        permutation = template_string
        for var, option in zip(variables, combination):
            permutation = permutation.replace('{' + var + '}', option)
        permutations.append(permutation)

    return permutations


What I needed is an algorithm to put both of these together to be able to process nested template strings and be able to process them no matter how deep the nests go.
I have attempted to use regular expressions to find nested brace pairs ,but the code just hangs.
Also, if there is a program that can accomplish this, please point the way.

Could you clarify the problem statement?

Do I understand correctly that the file 'animals.txt' contains words, each of which is written on a separate line? And all the files that can be mentioned in the input string have this structure?
Do I understand correctly that you need to extract words from all files and insert them into the input string instead of the template?


That is, with such input data: input string: "The {person, fox, {animals.txt, {other_animals.txt}}} jumped over the car" animals.txt: cat\n dog\n other_animals.txt: bear\n frog\n the program should output: The person jumped over the car The fox jumped over the car The cat jumped over the car The dog jumped over the car The bear jumped over the car The frog jumped over the car. I made this assumption by looking at example you gave. But I don't understand why in the code you create different combinations of words from files and substitute them? Can you provide more complex example?



Yes, I put the words on separate lines, but the post editor is forcing them on one. Assume all text files have a word or words that will get substituted in when the template is expanded.


Yes.


A {sculpture, painting} of a {seagull {on a pier, on a beach}, poodle {on a sofa, in a truck}}.
A sculpture of a seagull on a pier.
A sculpture of a seagull on a beach.
A sculpture of a poodle on a sofa.
A sculpture of a poodle in a truck.
A painting of a seagull on a pier.
A painting of a seagull on a beach.
A painting of a poodle on a sofa.
A painting of a poodle in a truck.

You said in the comments that you can have nested sets of options. In this case, the task of finding all possible options for the form of initial string turns into the task of traversing the tree of options. The descendants of each node here are nested sets of options.
To solve the problem in this setting, I can offer you this option
import typing


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items: typing.Any = []

    def push(self, item: typing.Any):
        self._items.append(item)

    def pop(self) -> typing.Any:
        self._items.pop()

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return len(self._items) == 0



def get_first_substitution_group(string: str) -> str:
    """
        Finds and returns the first available part of the string, 
        limited by the opening and closing brackets.
        Example: 
            string: 'A sculpture of a {seagull {on a pier, on a beach}}'

            result: 'seagull {on a pier, on a beach}'
    """
    stack = Stack()
    for i, сhar in enumerate(string):
        if сhar == '{':
            if stack.is_empty():
                start = i
            stack.push('{')
        elif сhar == '}':
            if stack.is_empty():
                raise Exception('Closing сharacter precedes the opening one')
            stack.pop()
            if stack.is_empty():
                return string[start + 1:i]

    if not stack.is_empty():
        raise Exception(
            'The number of opening characters is not equal '
            'to the number of closing ones'
        )


def extract_options(
    string: str, split_char:str = ','
) -> typing.Generator[str, None, None]:
    """
        Splits a string with a splitting character at the first level, 
        the parts of the string inside the brackets remain unchanged.
        Example: 
            string: 'seagull {on a pier, on a beach}, poodle {on a sofa, in a truck}'
            split_char: ','
            result: 
                first iteration: 'seagull {on a pier, on a beach}'
                second iteration: 'poodle {on a sofa, in a truck}'
    """
    stack = Stack()
    start = 0
    for i, сhar in enumerate(string):
        if сhar == '{':
            stack.push('{')
        elif сhar == '}':
            if stack.is_empty():
                raise Exception('Closing сharacter precedes the opening one')
            stack.pop()
        elif сhar == split_char:
            if stack.is_empty():
                yield string[start: i]
                start = i + 1

    yield string[start:]

    if not stack.is_empty():
        raise Exception(
            'The number of opening characters is not equal '
            'to the number of closing ones'
        )


def string_forms_generator(template: str) -> typing.Generator[str, None, None]:
    """
        Substitutes the options listed in brackets into the original string and
        provides in this way all possible forms of the string
        Example: 
            string: 'seagull {on a pier, on a beach}, poodle {on a sofa, in a truck}'
            split_char: ','
            result: 
                first iteration: 'seagull on a pier, poodle on a sofa'
                second iteration: 'seagull on a pier, poodle in a truck'
                third iteration: 'seagull on a beach, poodle on a sofa'
                fourth iteration: 'seagull on a beach, poodle in a truck'
    """
    first_substitution_group = get_first_substitution_group(template)

    if first_substitution_group is None:
        yield template
    else:
        for option in extract_options(first_substitution_group):
            yield from string_forms_generator(
                template.replace(
                    f'{{{first_substitution_group}}}', option.strip()
                )
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Here you can substitute values from files using your function 
    # `expand_template`

    template = (
        'A {sculpture, painting} of a {seagull {on a pier, on a beach}, '
        'poodle {on a sofa, in a truck}}'
    )
    for string_form in string_forms_generator(template):
        print(string_form)

The algorithm is simple.

we find the first group of options in the initial string using function get_first_substitution_group;
extract possible options from it (without changing them, if the option itself is a group of options, we use it as is) using function extract_options;
substitute first option in the string instead of the group of options;
repeat everything from the first step for the resulting string.

When there are no groups of options left in the line, i.e. all substitutions are made, we return string. After that, we roll back a step and substitute another option from the last group of options, if it was. And so on until all the options from the option groups are tried
Here I used a simple recursive depth-first traversal. If you have a high degree of nesting possible, then this solution will not work for you.
